# Set width of element to the width of its parent plus the padding of its parent

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an element whose side will line up with the parent's side, regardless of how much padding the parent has.

Normally, I know the padding of the parent, so I'd just have something like this:

```
<div style="padding: 20px">
    ...other contents...
    <footer style="margin: 0 -20px -20px"></footer>
</div>
```

That only works because I know the parent element has a `padding: 20px`.

Is there a way to stretch the footer to the appropriate size without knowing the padding of the parent, without javascript?

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/NvQQL/).

EDIT: The footer needs to cause the parent container to become larger in order to fit all the content AND the footer. Because of this `position: absolute;` likely wont work.

Comment: They're both block elements, so I'd just 1) put them underneath one another instead of one inside the other and 2) give them the same classes, and they'll come out the same. But that would be too easy, wouldn't it?

Comment: See this related topic: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: Box sizing won't help get the footer out of its container's content area and still be able to force the container to extend to accommodate its height.

Comment: Mr Lister, that's my next plan of action... assuming there's no way to accomplish what I've asked. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS:

```css
article {
    background-color: #eee;
    margin: 20px;
    position:relative;

}
article:after{
    content:' ';
    display:block;
    width:1px;
    height:40px /* Height of footer */;
    clear:both;
}
footer {
    background-color: #ddd;
    position:absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    padding: 10px 0;

    /* this only works for a container with
     * padding: 20px;
     * How can this work for a container
     * any amount of padding, without
     * javascript? */
}
```

http://jsbin.com/arosuz/4/

Comment: Very similar to Ligth's answer, but it still has an issue when the footer becomes larger. The footer will overlap the text above instead of making the container larger.

Comment: Ah, well, you didn't mention you have a variable height footer.  I'm afraid I don't know of a solution to your problem given all your assumptions.  You can't use `position:absolute` because that will take the footer out of the normal flow, and since you don't know the height, you can't simulate it being in there to have the article accomodate it's size.  It would be much simpler if you don't mind changing your HTML a bit.  Like placing the article body in it's own container that has padding.

Comment: If you don't mind changing your HTML a bit, here's a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/NvQQL/2/

Answer (score 3):

When you do padding, you are telling to its contents to expand doest matter what like in the second case. In the first case you had to add padding to both and then they line up.

To solved i use `position:relative` in the parent div and then in the footer i use `position:absolute`.Here the result: http://jsbin.com/arosuz/1/edit

When to use position :absolute inside a relative content, that tell it that now its content will be his parent container(relative).

Here a good tutorial:
http://learnlayout.com/position.html

Comment: do `position: absolute;` elements handle `width:100%` differently than other elements?

Comment: Also, at http://jsbin.com/arosuz/3/edit : I changed the footer to be semi transparent. It is not lining up vertically. Also, won't this mess up the container when the footer is large? ...This is pretty close to what I'm looking for though.

Comment: @uber5001 yes, absolute makes honor to its name, everything that it does, it does it by its own way without taking into account the other, but respectful in some cases that does not affect any element and flow stay intact.

Comment: @Ligth to make the footer stay at the bottom of the page, regardless the padding of its parent, you can add: `bottom: 0px;`.

Answer (score 0):

If your interested in the parent div padding CSS value you could also use this.

```
     var padding = $(this).parent("div").css("padding");
```

Comment: Oops. Sorry, forgot to mention I don't want to use javascript. I've edited the question. Thanks for your answer though!